# Reversing number in c++ with arrays

Tags: c++

I am trying to find the reverse of the number entered by the user :
This is my main.cpp code

```
   int number=0;
   cout<< " enter a number";
   cin>>number;
   reverse( number);
```

this is my function .cpp code

```
 int reverse( int number){
    int last=0;
    int i=0;
    int array1[10]={0} ;
    int check=number;
    while ( check!=0){
        last=check%10;
        array1[i]=last;
        i++;
        check=number/10;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j <= i; ++j) {
        cout<<array1[j];

    }
    return 0;

}
```

It only asks me to enter a number then does not give any output.
what should I correct?

Comment: Side note: Cheat like hell and don't convert the user's input into an `int`. If you take the input as a string, it's already divided up into easily accessible digits. If you feel the need, you can ensure that all of the characters read are digits while reversing with `isdigit`

Comment: @user4581301, "Cheat like hell" should come with a warning label. Anybody whose solution meets 100% of the problem spec should be prepared to fight for credit if the implementation doesn't work the same way under the covers that some TA (or even the prof) _expected_ it to work. (Don't ask me how I know!)

Comment: I too have had my ass kicked by weird expectations. But at the end of the day, [the compiler doesn't care about your piddly little expectations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if) We had a question the other day from an asker wondering how `memcpy` and `memset` wound up in their code when they deliberately avoided them by writing their own loops. The compiler recognized the loop behaviour and replaced the loops with library calls that did the same thing (and probably did it faster).

Comment: Why don’t you just treat the number as a `string`, start to finish? When the user enters (e.g.) `987654321098765432109876543210987654321098765432109876543210`, a `string`-based solution will work fine whereas your `int` wannabe-solution will fail miserably.

Comment: Do you expect reversing a reversed value will produce the original value?  What do you expect the reverse of `100` to be?

Comment: What if the number is negative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check=number/10 will be *check=check/10*

and j<=i will be j<i

Answer (score 0):

did you try:

```
cout<< reverse( number);
```

Comment: yes i did but nothing happened.

Comment: Please add more info and run it first to make it more useful.